# Why am I getting multiple "cannot find module.." errors after a fresh install of Microsoft.PowerBI.JavaScript

Tags: typescript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Hi I'm trying to use the Powerbis javascript client to interact with my embedded report however I get over 30+ errors. I simply followed the bower instructions on the github page: [Power BI Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZmF8.png).

Here is a list of errors alongside my file structure
[image]

It looks to me like I'm missing some files?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing some of the dependencies for the project. One that I can see from the scene shot is powerbi-models. You can try "npm install" that should install all of the dependencies listed in the project.json file.